# using jQuery .hover() with absoltutely positioned layered elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code to display an absolutely positioned (layered with z-index) element ontop of the hovered element.  When the mouse interferes with the element that is faded in on hover and causes mouseout / mouseover to fire repeatedly causing adverse effects.

What is the best way to code this so the faded in element does not interfere with the hover event?

```
$("div-below-faded-in-element").hover(function(e) {
    $("hovered-element-positioned-on-top-of-div").fadeIn()
},
function() {
    $("hovered-element-positioned-on-top-of-div").fadeOut()
})
```

Thanks in advance, sorry if this is confusing kind of hard to explain.

**jsFiddle Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/AWm66/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Check out this jsFiddle that I made. I just added a wrapper for btm and top and added the event handler for it.

**[jsFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/RyanAdriano/AWm66/8/)**

Comment: this does not work.  I generally use with all hover events to eliminate multiple events firing one after the other. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle sample?

Comment: It was easier to understand with a jsFiddle sample :P. Updated my answer above.

Comment: +1 Ryan that seems to work nicely, btw, when editing your answers, please don't delete the previous bits, just update above or below -  - it makes it easier to see what's been tried/tested, and follow the comments below - saw you did it in another thread too ;) thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Animations may be stopped globally by setting the property `$.fx.off` to true. When this is done, all animation methods will immediately set elements to their final state when called, rather than displaying an effect.

When .stop() is called on an element, the currently-running animation (if any) is immediately stopped. If, for instance, an element is being hidden with .slideUp() when .stop() is called, the element will now still be displayed, but will be a fraction of its previous height. Callback functions are not called.

If more than one animation method is called on the same element, the later animations are placed in the effects queue for the element. These animations will not begin until the first one completes. When .stop() is called, the next animation in the queue begins immediately. If the clearQueue parameter is provided with a value of true, then the rest of the animations in the queue are removed

Comment: I am not sure how this applies to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but I've been noticing this on some hover effects I've been trying too

however for your use case would [`fadeTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) do - I tried it and it seems to work better, it animates the opacity of the  element

```
$("#above").hover(function () {
    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.0)
},
function(){
     $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1.0)
});
```

#### Example: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/qZHYB/)

Comment: This produces the same effect as I had previously.  I have the jsFiddle updated with your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/AWm66/6/

Comment: ah so it does with your code, never saw your fiddle before making mine, it works fine for the complete overlap - LOL -I think a wrapper div with the hover function attached to it would be the best solution